# Python bug with empty list

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.6

I'm using python to try to emulate the basic functions of Inform 7 ([inform7.com](http://inform7.com)). When I am trying to set up the rooms printing out all the objects in them, and there are no objects in the room, it still prints out `In this room there is a`. The relevant part of the code is here.

```
def __repr__(self):
    if self.room_firstrun:
        for i in things:
            if things[i] == self.name:
                self.objects_in_room.append(i)
        self.room_firstrun = False

    fullstring = 'In this room, there is a '
    for i in self.objects_in_room:
        if not self.objects_in_room:
            fullstring = ''
            break
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[len(self.objects_in_room) - 1] and len(self.objects_in_room) > 2:
            stringtoappend = ', and a ' + i + '.'
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[len(self.objects_in_room) - 1] and len(self.objects_in_room) == 2:
            stringtoappend = ' and a ' + i + '.'
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[len(self.objects_in_room) - 1] and len(self.objects_in_room) == 1:
            stringtoappend = i + '.'
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[0]:
            stringtoappend = i
        else:
            stringtoappend = ', a ' + i
    fullstring += stringtoappend
    stringtoappend = ''
    return '\n----------' + self.name + '----------\n\n' + self.desc + '\n\n' + fullstring
```

. The line `if not self.objects_in_room: fullstring = '' break` is never being reached, even when I have verified that the list is empty by removing all the items. I've been trying to fix it for a while, but it hasn't been working. Also annoying, when I have two items in a room, it isn't displaying the first. Maybe I should put that in another question. Thanks in advance for an answer!

Comment: Move that statement out of the loop. The loop won't run at all if the list is empty. Second, why are you using stringtoappend instead of just adding them to the fullstring

Comment: Um.... I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Oh never mind i accidentally deleted it *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if not self.objects_in_room` was never reached because it is inside the for loop, and that the for loop only runs when `self.objects_in_room` is not empty. To fix this, put `if not self.objects_in_room` outside the loop

```
def __repr__(self):
    if self.room_firstrun:
        for i in things:
            if things[i] == self.name:
                self.objects_in_room.append(i)
        self.room_firstrun = False

    fullstring = 'In this room, there is a '
    if not self.objects_in_room:
            fullstring = ''
    for i in self.objects_in_room:

        if i == self.objects_in_room[len(self.objects_in_room) - 1] and len(self.objects_in_room) > 2:
            fullstring += ', and a {0}.'.format(i)
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[len(self.objects_in_room) - 1] and len(self.objects_in_room) == 2:
            fullstring += ' and a {0}.'.format(i)
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[len(self.objects_in_room) - 1] and len(self.objects_in_room) == 1:
            fullstring += '{0}.'.format(i)
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[0]:
            fullstring += i
        else:
            fullstring += ', a {0}'.format(i)
    return '\n----------' + self.name + '----------\n\n' + self.desc + '\n\n' + fullstring
```

or you can do: if you're using python 3 using the `for..else` statement.

```
def __repr__(self):
    if self.room_firstrun:
        for i in things:
            if things[i] == self.name:
                self.objects_in_room.append(i)
        self.room_firstrun = False

    fullstring = 'In this room, there is a '

    for i in self.objects_in_room:

        if i == self.objects_in_room[len(self.objects_in_room) - 1] and len(self.objects_in_room) > 2:
            fullstring += ', and a {0}.'.format(i)
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[len(self.objects_in_room) - 1] and len(self.objects_in_room) == 2:
            fullstring += ' and a {0}.'.format(i)
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[len(self.objects_in_room) - 1] and len(self.objects_in_room) == 1:
            fullstring += '{0}.'.format(i)
        elif i == self.objects_in_room[0]:
            fullstring += i
        else:
            fullstring += ', a {0}'.format(i)
    else:
        fullstring = ''
    return '\n----------' + self.name + '----------\n\n' + self.desc + '\n\n' + fullstring
```

and why are you using stringtoappend? why not just adding it directly to the fullstring?